# Interpreting hamming loss for multilabel classification

Tags: python, model-evaluation, accuracy, boosting, multilabel

I have a multi label - multi class classifier that aims to predict the top 3 selling products out of 11 possible for a given day.

Using scikit learn's OneVSRest with XgBoost as an estimator, the model gets a hamming loss of 0.25.

Im not familiar with HL, I have mainly done binary classification with roc_auc in the past.

Is this an okay score and how can I describe the effectiveness of the model?
does it mean that the model predicts 0,25 * 11 =  2,75 labels wrong on average?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

this slide shows a good example, HL=4/(5*4)=0.2
more information refer to https://users.ics.aalto.fi/jesse/talks/Multilabel-Part01.pdf